# @openapi is not working/recognized in typescript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger-ui, openapi-generator, swagger-jsdocs

I have defined the swagger.ts as below:

```
import swaggerJSDoc from "swagger-jsdoc";
import { version } from '../package.json';

const options: swaggerJSDoc.Options = {
    definition: {
        openapi: "3.0.0",
        info: {
            title: "abc project",
            version
        }
    },
    apis: ["./routes/rootRouter.ts"]
};

export default options;
```

and i'm trying to document the api is below:

```
 /**
   * @openapi
   * /isAlive:
   *  get:
   *     tags:
   *     - Healthcheck
   *     description: Responds if the app is up and running
   *     responses:
   *       200:
   *         description: App is up and running
   */
router.get('/abc.json', (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    'name' : 'sdf',
    'org' : 'sdf',
    'rev': 'local'
  });
});
```

I have done the necessary coding in app.ts. But when the server starts it displays the swagger page but doesn't display the apis documented. Anybody have faced the same issues?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, just change the apis array to be like this:

```
apis: ["**/*.ts"]
```

Source: https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc/issues/150

### BONUS:

With this fix you can probably have some issues on the prod environment since once the project is delivered to prod, it goes without `*.ts` files and swagger will not find any endpoint.

A solution for this problem could be to use something like this:

```
apis: ["**/*.{ts,js"]
```